# Script or command to sync time with TimeServer?

Tags: linux, time

I am a programmer working on embedded linux,

On my device, I need to set time everytime when I want to use it to check my program.

Is there any command or script which sets time from some Internet timeserver everytime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely which ever linux disto your working on has a NTP package which will allow you to sync with any pulic NTP server

Tutorial for ubuntu(should be similar in other distros):
http://nixtechnica.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-synchronize-time-with-ntp.html

Time servers:
http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/ntp.html

Answer (score 1):

You will  have to have the ntp package installed.

If ntp is running:

```
ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
```

otherwise without ntp running, I believe it would be:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```